# Organizing Files Between Files Saved in External SD Card and Files Saved in Internal Drive

Tags: external-sd, internal-storage, file-transfer, storage

For example, let's say I want to take some settings for organizing the directory target. When I take photos, I want to automatically saved directly onto the removable SD card (external drive) while apps downloaded and installed are stored in internal drive. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Redirect File Organiser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tobino.redirectsfree&hl=en).

The usage by dev is explained at /r/android over [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1qqpm0/).

Hope this is what you are looking for.